# SELECT id WHERE id equals a passed value

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing the "id" value from one page media_main.php to another player.php via:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return popitup('player.php?pid=<?php echo ("$row->id");?>')" title="Listen">
```

On the player.php page I would like to select certain data WHERE the id equals that id that was passed.  So far I have this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, media_date, media_title, given_by, filename FROM media WHERE id = ?? ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I'm not sure how to work the WHERE clause since it will change and not be a static number.  I only want to select the data when the id to equal the passed id value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to Clive's response, if you know that the ID is only numerical, you can cast it to an Integer instead of escaping it.

If there is any erroneous input it will just cast it to 0.

```
$pid = (int) $_GET['pid'];

$query = "SELECT id, media_date, media_title, given_by, filename FROM media WHERE id = '$pid' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: @Clive as a matter of fact, in *this* code quotes are totally useless.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Yep you're right, Dimme and I have nicely messed this one up between us :)

Comment: Although quotes are totally useless in this piece of code, it is a good practice to always use them.

I think Nick got his question answered, which is the main point of stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, a very good reason is that you might forget to use them in cases where you really need to use them. If you always use them the chances forgetting when it is important to use them are less. Do the quotes cause any harm? No...

Comment: Downvoting my CORRECT answer which doesn't contain any errors because you don't like my coding style is a bad practice though.

Comment: @Dimme, yes this did work for me.  I appreciate your time and stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your code you're passing the ID in via a URL parameter (`pid`), in which case you just need to escape the string to prevent SQL injection and build your query up using the resulting id:

```
$pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pid']);

$query = "SELECT id, media_date, media_title, given_by, filename FROM media WHERE id = '$pid' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

It would probably be wise to check that the passed value is numeric.

Also, if `id` is a primary/unique key then you can remove the `ORDER BY` clause from the query as it will make no difference.

**EDIT**
The answer has been updated as suggested in the comments below to include quotes around the SQL argument.

Comment: $pid in the query should be like '$pid'

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Hmm I can't see it, where's the vulnerability?

Comment: Do you have an idea of SQL injections at all?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I *thought* I had a good handle on SQL injection but obviously not...would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Here it is, mysql_real_escape_string is not sufficient.  
player.php?pid=-1 UNION SELECT,2,3,4,5 col FROM table_name

Comment: @LaithShadeed: Thanks that makes sense, in that case I imagine using quotes as Dimme suggested is the right way to go?

Comment: exactly we always need those quotes because there are always those bad cracker trying crack our systems. But as a better engineering practice, we prefer using prepared statements because working in large team, someone may forget to add those quotes.

Comment: @LaithShadeed: Thanks for the clarification, I use PDO these days so I must be rustier than I thought with injection vulnerabilities :)

Comment: @Clive: yes, proper usage PDO is **perfect** it least for now, in future maybe someone will find new crack for that :P

Comment: @LaithShadeed sure. While whatever tool is used without understanding, but just as a sort of habit, there is always a danger. For example, someday a PDO user will face the need of inserting an indentifier into the query based on user unput.